# Fit an iOS application developed for 4 inch screen to 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I am writing my first iOS app and just realized a serious problem. I was using storyboard for a 4 inch iphone screen and forgot to take 3.5 inch screens into consideration. :( 
 It seems that this could be relatively fixed easily if I have done everything in code. But unfortunately, I have used storyboard for some parts of my app. It seems that the table views are fit perfectly but the views with some fixed subviews fail. 
 Could anyone please give me some suggestions on how to fix this? Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Well doing it in code would've been much worse !, you're on the right track !, what you need to do is change all your fixed subviews to be resizable, also you need to lookup AutoLayout !

Comment: I realize this is not as specific as you might want, but I would suggest learning about "constraints" in Interface Builder. You will likely be able to accomplish what you need. The recent Xcode 5.1 makes them a bit more manageable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what auto layout exists for. You can create a UI, using storyboards, that works perfectly for both screen sizes. You can toggle a setting in the storyboard to have it display the two different screen sizes, so you can easily see how your views will move and resize. There is also a preview mode for the storyboard that lets you see how it will look. It also lets you see how it will look on both iOS 6 and iOS 7, so that you can make sure that your UI looks good on both assuming you still support iOS 6.

If you had done this in code, it would probably have been a whole lot more complicated, especially since you have to run it each time to see what changes when you adjust your code. Graphical layout tools such as Interface Builder (what allows you to view and edit storyboards and XIB files) make supporting multiple screen sizes very easy. Plus, generally it's not too hard to make a screen designed for a 4" screen work with a 3.5" screen, in some cases you just have to make things fit a little closer together, or perhaps have the content in a scroll view.